# Invalid certificate while Set SSL for SSRS

Tags: ssl, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, self-signed

I have SSRS link, And we are planning to set SSL for it.
So I have went with the following steps on the server:

- Generate a Self-Signing Certificate with Powershell
  by running the following commands

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\my -dnsname <MyHostNameServer>

$pwd=ConvertTo-SecureString "password1" -asplainText -force

$file="C:\temp\<MYHOSTNAMEServer>.pfx"

Export-PFXCertificate -cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\<Thumbprint produced during first command> -f

Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $file cert:\LocalMachine\root -Password $pwd
```

- Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager
- Click Connect at the “Reporting Services Configuration Connection” Screen

[Reporting services Configuration Manager pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN77x.png)

- Click on Web Site URL in the left-hand pane window
- In the “HTTPS Certificate” drop-down box select the certificate you installed.  You will see the Port text box pre-fill and the Report Server Web Services URL pre-fill.
- Click Apply

[Web URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acyr3.jpg)

And I have tested the URL , with https and worked 
[link is working pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NuW2.jpg)

The issue now ! the HTTPS link works perfectly in the server, but with any other users ( from my laptop ) I got "invalid Certificate" ! and it seems not a trusted certificate

Could you please assist me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers like Chrome and Firefox will only accept CA-signed server certificates as trusted certificates for HTTPS. There are also other requirements such as SubjectAlternativeName extensions and the algorithm used for the certificate (SHA-1 is not recommended and the browser may present a warning).

[Google provides documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543?hl=en) for a correct setup of your TLS server certificate, mentioning the requirement of it being CA-signed and so on.

Most likely if the TLS configuration is correct and working on Chrome it will work on other browsers. Internet Explorer is the outlier insecure browser that does not warn users of a potential MITM attack when the server presents a self-signed certificate.